# Why does UITextView flicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, flicker

I have a `UITextView`, when I execute `textView.attributedText = ...`, it has a certain probability of flickering. I don’t know what caused it, but I have some clues:

1. When changing `attributedText`, it will cause flickering.
2. When I change the `attributedText`, it is also accompanied by the code to modify the `contentOffset`, because I want the position to remain the same before and after the change. The code is as follows:

```swift
let oldOffset = textView.contentOffset

textView.attributedText = ...

// If it is not delayed, the modification will not take effect
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
    textView.contentOffset = oldOffset
}
```

Below is my code to create `UITextView`:

```swift
public override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer? = nil) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        
    config()
}

func config() {
    
    textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(
        top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10
    )

    delaysContentTouches = false
    canCancelContentTouches = true
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
    backgroundColor = .clear
        
    textAlignment = .left
    isEditable = false
        
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
    scrollsToTop = false
    isScrollEnabled = false
    bounces = false
        
    textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false
}
```

I suspect that one of these two reasons is causing the flickering problem, but other reasons cannot be ruled out.

If anyone can help me, it would be very grateful!

Supplement: My `UITextView` is nested in `UIScrollView` and uses AutoLayout. If necessary, please leave a message, I will add the relevant code

Comment: If you replace characters, maybe replacing directly on `textStorage` instead of resetting the whole `attributedText` might be working: `textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in:...)`

Comment: @Larme This doesn't seem to solve the problem...

Comment: Have you got any solution? I am having the same issue.